# How to remove extra characters in a string in c#?

Tags: c#, format, substring, format-string

I have a string like this:

```
"\"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=dbname; user Id=sa;Password=1;Integrated Security=false\""
```

But I need to create a string like this:

```
"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=dbname; user Id=sa;Password=1;Integrated Security=false"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Searched how to take a substring from a string?

Comment: yes. but my string have 2 extra charachter at first "\ and 2 extra charachters one before the last \"

Comment: Look up Replace() or just take a substring of the original but without the first two characters, and without the last three characters. Then add a `"` to the end of it using addition `+ '"'`

Comment: my string is not Static string. every time created a difference string that i must remove 2 charachters at first "\ and 2 extra charachter one before the last (\")

Comment: thanks. it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
string myOriginalString = "\"Whatever\"";
MySubString = mystring.Substring(1, mystring.Length - 2);
```

Comment: Glad we were able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\"\"" by \".

```
myString.Replace("\"\"", "\"")
```